# Spring Boot Kafka newbie question on serializing / deserializing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I'm new to Kafka (using Spring Boot 2.2.4) and I'm seeing samples where the KafkaTemplate's are String, String to just send a string. I was looking at sending Json objects and I'm seeing 2 different approaches there... some folks are using String, Object and some are using String, TheActualModelClass.

Is there pros/cons between the two? I'm kind of assuming the main diff is that the typed template would only be good for one model whereas the object could send any type to any topic? Anything beyond that?

Comment: There is nothing beyond "that". Use `Object` (or `SomeSuperClass`) for the value generic parameter if you send objects of different types or `SomeConcreteClass` if you only send one type. As @DeadPoll says below; you need a serializer that can handle multiple types.

Answer (score 3):

While I might be late in answering it , but it might be useful for those who are looking for solution.
You can look at detailed solution at https://github.com/CODINGSAINT/kafka-stream-spring

Think if we have a custom java bean

```
public class Quote {
private String content;
private Set<String> tags;
private String author;
}
```

You are required to write Kafka Producer as well as Consumer configurations

```
 /**
 * Configurations for KafkaStreams
 * @param kafkaProperties Will take defaults from application YAML or Properties file with spring.kafka
 * @return kafkaConfiguration
 */
@Bean(name= KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
public KafkaStreamsConfiguration kafkaConfiguration(final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties){
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getClientId());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, QuoteSerde.class.getName() );
    config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(config);
}

/**
 * The Stream which delegates each incoming topic to respective destination topic
 * @param kStreamsBuilder
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public KStream<String,Quote> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamsBuilder){
    KStream<String,Quote> stream=kStreamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic);
    for(String topic:allTopics){
        stream.filter((s, quote) -> quote.getTags().contains(topic)).to(topic);
    }
    return stream;

}

/**
 * Kafka ConsumerFactory configurations
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Quote> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            BytesDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

/**
 * Required Configuration for POJO to JSON
 * @return ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
 */
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Quote>
kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Quote> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

Then we require a Serializer

```
public class QuoteSerializer implements Serializer<Quote> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String s, Quote quote) {
        byte[] retVal = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(quote).getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

And a Deserializer

```
public class QuoteDeserializer implements Deserializer<Quote> {

    @Override
    public Quote deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Quote quote = null;
        try {
            quote = mapper.readValue(bytes, Quote.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return quote;
    }
}
```

To make use of both Serializer and Deserializer a Serde

```
public class QuoteSerde implements Serde<Quote> {
    public QuoteSerde() {
    }

    @Override
    public Serializer<Quote> serializer() {
        return new QuoteSerializer();
    }

    @Override
    public Deserializer<Quote> deserializer() {
        return new QuoteDeserializer();
    }
}
```

**Now our listener can listen**

```
@Component
public class TopicConsumers {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicConsumers.class);

    @Value("#{'${kafka.topic.output}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> allTopics;

    /**
     * For simplicity we are listening all topics at one listener
     */

    @KafkaListener(id = "allTopics", topics = "#{'${kafka.topic.output}'.split(',')}",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consume(@Payload Quote quote,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String incomingTopic,
                        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts
    ) {
        LOGGER.info("Incoming quote {}-> {}", incomingTopic, quote);
    }
}
```

Below is application.yml file

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
    client-id : quotes-app
    bootstrap-server:
      - localhost:9091
      - localhost:9001
      - localhost:9092
    template:
      default-topic: quotes
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: com.codingsaint.learning.kafkastreamspring.QuoteSerializer
    consumer:
      properties:
        partition:
          assignment:
            strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
      group-id: random-consumer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: com.codingsaint.learning.kafkastreamspring.QuoteDeserializer
---
kafka:
  topic:
    input: quotes
    output: business,education,faith,famous-quotes,friendship,future,happiness,inspirational,life,love,nature,politics,proverb,religion,science,success,technology
```

Answer (score 2):

While using spring-kafka library i would suggest use the spring `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` to avoid lot's of boiler plate code, you can find more information about [Spring Serialization, Deserialization, and Message Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes)

Apache kafka only provides high-level API for serializing and deserializing, so user need a custom implementation for serializing or deserializing

```
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<T>
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer<T>
```

> Apache Kafka provides a high-level API for serializing and deserializing record values as well as their keys. It is present with the org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer and org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer abstractions with some built-in implementations. Meanwhile, we can specify serializer and deserializer classes by using Producer or Consumer configuration properties.

But `Spring-kafka` provides `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` based on `ObjectMapper`

> **Spring for Apache Kafka also provides JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer implementations that are based on the Jackson JSON object mapper.** The JsonSerializer allows writing any Java object as a JSON byte[]. The JsonDeserializer requires an additional Class targetType argument to allow the deserialization of a consumed byte[] to the proper target object.

And it also provides deserializing different type of `JSON` objects to respective java POJO classes using [Type Mappings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#serdes-mapping-types) and [@KafkaListener on a Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener)

Comment: Apache also includes a JSONSerializer using Jackson

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string. At the end of the code sequence, your model object would be serialized to bytes anyway

Which one you prefer depends how much Kafka serializer code you want to abstract away